# Debugging code when problem occurs during promise

Tags: javascript

I have some code that uses a promise to return some data from a server, and catches the error.

The problem is after I display some text and buttons, another part of my code removes it after the function returns.

Debugging line by line I can't find the problem, because everything looks fine when my function runs, but after it returns it calls promise.js, workque.js, callback.js, etc.

I can hold down F10 and it endlessly scrolls through random code unrelated to my script, so I'm not sure how to locate the issue.

Should I use/is there someway to prevent the code from returning? Or how should I debug this? I run into similar issues often, I feel like I must be missing some process or tool to handle situations like this?

This is my the part of my code the problem occurs at, but I know it's irrelevant since there's no way to figure it out just from this:

```
 .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code
            var errorMessage = error.message
            console.log('userSubmitEmailAndPassword Error signing in user. Error code: ', errorCode, ' ', errorMessage)
            if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                userInvalidEmail()
            } else if (errorCode === 'auth/user-disabled') {
                userUserDisabled()
            } else if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
                userInvalidEmail()
            } else if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                userInvalidPassword()
            }
        })

function userInvalidEmail() {
    console.log('userInvalidEmail email is ', new_user_dict['email'])
    showInfo("I don't see an account with that e-mail address. \n\nWould you like to make a new account or try again?")
    hideInputText()
    showButton(left_button, 'New Account', newUser)
    showButton(right_button, 'Try Again', userLogin)
}
```

Comment: You may be able to "ignore" or "blackbox" external scripts while debugging to help track down where in *your* code the issue might be.